# how to access all the surrounding elements of outer ring in a matrix

Tags: java, search, matrix, grid, cells

In a recent interview I had, they asked me this question:

*Consider a battlefield to be made up of square cells of unit dimensions. A soldier on the battlefield can move from a cell to all(8) of it's neighboring cells. soldier has a gun with him which he can shoot the targets up to any distance along any of the 8 possible directions (north,east,west,south,north-east,north-west,south-east,south-west). also some cells are bulletproof which prevents bullets to pass but soldier can walk over them as if it were a normal cell.he can destroy the target from a bulletproof cell but not from a cell behind it.*

*Given the position of the target, starting position of a target and position of all the bullet proof cells. you have to tell the position of closest shooting point i.e the cell from which, the soldier can shoot the target and is closest to the starting position of the soldier. if there are more than one such cells, output all of them.*

Input specifications :

I) size of the battlefield { integer pair (N,M) : battlefield will be of N*M size )

II) starting position of the soldier {integer pair (i,j)}

III) position of the target {integer pair (x,y) : position of the cell on which target is mounted}

IV) position of all the bullet proof cells { list of integer pair a#b : each element in the list is a position of a bullet proof cell}*

Output specifications :

Sequential list of integer pair i#j (cell) that are closest shoot points and must follow row wise traversal.

Note: if the output list contains four shoot points : (2,1), (1,2), (3,2), (2,4) on a 4x4 battle field. 
then the correct output will be {1#2,2#1,2#4,3#2} not {1#2,2#1,3#2,2#4}

Example: Input : {2,2} {2,1} {2,2} {1#1,1#2} Output : 2#1

**My Code:**

```
public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] size = {4, 4};
    int[] startPt = {1, 1};
    int[] endPt = {4, 2};
    String[] impenetrable = {"2#2", "3#3","3#2"};
    Process(size, startPt, endPt, impenetrable);
}

public static void Process(int[] size, int[] startPt, int[] endPt, String[] impenStr) {
    //Initialize starting position.
    int x = startPt[0] - 1;
    int y = startPt[1] - 1;
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    int[][] direction = {{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}};
    int[][] board = new int[size[0]][size[1]];

    board[startPt[0] - 1][startPt[1] - 1] = 1;
    board[endPt[0] - 1][endPt[1] - 1] = 2;

    //Impenetrable Points
    for (String p : impenStr) {
        String[] tmp = p.split("#");
        board[Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]) - 1][Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]) - 1] = 99;
    }

    System.out.println("The Board:");

    for (int m = 0; m < board.length; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < board.length; n++) {
            System.out.print(board[m][n] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    while (output.isEmpty()) {
        output = Surroundings(direction, endPt[0], endPt[1], board);
        //for (int m = 0; m < board.length; m++) {
          //  for (int n = 0; n < board.length; n++) {
            //    if(m!=startPt[0] - 1 || n!=startPt[1] - 1){

              //  }
            //}
        //}
        direction[0][0] = direction[0][0] - 1; // up
        direction[0][1] = direction[0][1];

        direction[1][0] = direction[1][0] + 1; // Down
        direction[1][1] = direction[1][1];

        direction[2][0] = direction[2][0]; // Left
        direction[2][1] = direction[2][1] - 1;

        direction[3][0] = direction[3][0]; // right
        direction[3][1] = direction[3][1] + 1;

        direction[4][0] = direction[4][0] - 1; // NE
        direction[4][1] = direction[4][1] + 1;

        direction[5][0] = direction[5][0] + 1; // SW
        direction[5][1] = direction[5][1] - 1;

        direction[6][0] = direction[6][0] + 1; // SE
        direction[6][1] = direction[6][1] + 1;

        direction[7][0] = direction[7][0] - 1; // NW
        direction[7][1] = direction[7][1] - 1;
        count++;


        if (!output.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.toArray()));
}

public static List<String> Surroundings(int[][] direction, int targetX, int targetY, int[][] board) {
    String string = "";
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < direction.length; i++) {
        try {
            if (board[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] == 99) {
                board[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] = 0;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        if (checkDirections(board, direction[i][0], direction[i][1], targetX - 1, targetY - 1) == true) {
            string = string + (direction[i][0] + 1) + "#" + (direction[i][1] + 1);
        }
        try {
            if (board[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] == 0) {
                board[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] = 99;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }

        if (!string.equals("")) {
            output.add(string);
            string = "";
        }


    }
    return output;
}

public static boolean checkDirections(int[][] battleField, int x, int y, int finalX, int finalY) {
    return North(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || South(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || West(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || East(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || NE(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || SE(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || NW(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true
            || SW(battleField, x, y, finalX, finalY) == true;
}

public static boolean North(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return North(board, x - 1, y, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean South(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return South(board, x + 1, y, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean West(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return West(board, x, y + 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean East(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return East(board, x, y - 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean NE(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return NE(board, x - 1, y + 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean SW(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return SW(board, x + 1, y - 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean SE(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return SE(board, x + 1, y + 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}

public static boolean NW(int[][] board, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= board.length || y < 0 || y >= board.length || board[x][y] == 99) {
        return false;
    } else if (x == targetX && y == targetY) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return NW(board, x - 1, y - 1, targetX, targetY);
    }
}}
```

**Where I got stuck:**

[image]
Consider this image to be the battlefield and the yellow block to be the starting point.

In my code, for each loop, I go on searching through the elements of the outer ring.

I get the correct solution for all the blocks horizontally, vertically and diagonally.(Blue Blocks in the image).

But I am unable to access the red blocks. How do I access them too?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `main` method has a fixed number (8) of cells that it is checking at each step. This isn't going to work as each 'step' outwards actually increases the number of cells you should be checking by 8.

Given the number of cells you are checking is pretty small the simplest solution is probably to just check every cell on the board rather than stepping outwards. You can maintain a variable with the minimum distance to the target as you go.

The code would look something like this:

```
int minDistanceToTarget = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for each position on the board
    if position can hit target
        if distance < minDistanceToTarget
            minDistanceToTarget = distance
            output = ""
        if distance == minDistanceToTarget
            add position to output
```

Hopefully you see how that works: it reset the output whenever it finds a closer position that can hit the target and then adds all positions at that distance to the output.

As an aside, I think your code would be a lot neater if you encapsulated your positions in a `Position` class rather than storing as a second dimension in your array. Something like:

```
enum Direction {
    N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW;

    public int getRowDelta();
    public int getColDelta();
}

class Position
    private final int row;
    private final int col;

    public Position(int row, int col);
    public int distanceTo(Position other);
    public Position move(Direction direction);
}

class Board {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final Position start;
    private final Position target;
    private final List<Position> bulletproofCells;

    public Board(String input);
    public String getOutput();
}
```

You will find you can remove the duplication of code in methods if you encapsulate logic in classes such as these.